# Looping video in iOS cause a small pause/flash (MPMoviePlayerController & AVPlayer)

Tags: ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, avplayer

I'm really going crazy with my welcome view controller.

I have a video in background in continuos loop but every solution that I used causes a small pause/flash when the video is finished and loop.

I use two solution: **MPMoviePlayerController** and **AVPlayer** from AVFoundation but I got the same result, a small white flash when video is looped for replay.

### My MPMoviePlayerController solution (I prefer a fix for this)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *videoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"welcome_video" withExtension:@"mp4"];

    self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];

    self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    self.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;

    self.moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.frame;
    [self.view insertSubview:self.moviePlayer.view atIndex:0];

    [self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

    // Loop video
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(loopVideo) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:self.moviePlayer];
}

- (void)loopVideo
{
    [self.moviePlayer play];
}
```

## My AVPlayer solution

```
 (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSError *sessionError = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:&sessionError];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&sessionError];

    //Set up player
    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"welcome_video" ofType:@"mp4"]];
    AVAsset *avAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:movieURL];
    AVPlayerItem *avPlayerItem =[[AVPlayerItem alloc]initWithAsset:avAsset];
    self.avplayer = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithPlayerItem:avPlayerItem];
    AVPlayerLayer *avPlayerLayer =[AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.avplayer];
    [avPlayerLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
    [avPlayerLayer setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.movieView.layer addSublayer:avPlayerLayer];

    //Config player
    [self.avplayer seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
    [self.avplayer setVolume:0.0f];
    [self.avplayer setActionAtItemEnd:AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                 name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                               object:[self.avplayer currentItem]];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playerStartPlaying)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.avplayer pause];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.avplayer play];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification 
{
    AVPlayerItem *p = [notification object];
    [p seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
}

- (void)playerStartPlaying
{
    [self.avplayer play];
}
```

What's wrong with these implementation? I really try different fixes found on this site but nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm.. I might have an idea for the `AVPlayer`-approach.

The `AVPlayer` has this method:

```
- (void)setRate:(float)rate
           time:(CMTime)itemTime
     atHostTime:(CMTime)hostClockTime
```

This means that you can specify WHEN you want the `AVPlayer` to start at `kCMTimeZero`. I have not actually used it, but I have an idea for how it can work.

You need to know exactly the moment you start the video the first time. I see you have your own `-(void)playerStartPlaying` which is called by the `notificationCenter` on `didBecomeActive`. I suggest using this method for app variations of `[player play];`, so put

```
[self playerStartPlaying];
```

inside `viewDidAppear` instead of `[self.avplayer play];`. It might be good enough.

If you here manage to find the device's `hostClockTime`, and add the length of the video, you should end up with the exact time when you want it to start from scratch. I am not testing any of this, and I'm typing from head, so you need to *understand* what I'm doing, and fix it yourself.

```
- (void)playerStartPlaying
{
    //The device's hostClockTime. Basically a number indicating how long the device has been powered on.
    CMTime hostClockTime = CMClockGetHostTimeClock;

    //A CMTime indicating when you want the video to play the next time.
    CMTime nextPlay = CMTimeAdd(hostClockTime, self.avplayer.currentItem.duration);
    /* I don't know if that was correct or not, but you'll find out */

    //Start playing if we're not already playing. There might be an avplayer.isPlaying or something, I don't know, this is probably working as well..
    if(self.avplayer.rate != 1.0)
        [self.avplayer play];

    //Tell the player to restart the video at the correct time.
    [self.avplayer setRate:1.0 time:kCMTimeZero atHostTime:nextPlay];
}
```

You'll have to remove the entire `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification`-thing. When the video has reached the end, it's already too late. What we're doing now is telling it when to play the second turn **when we start the first**. We want nothing to happen when `didPlayToEndTime` is fired, we're handling it manually.

So, if you understand what I have done above, you'll also notice that the video only will play twice. We tell the video to play, at the same time as we tell it to replay at `time = now+videoLength`. When *that* replay is done, nothing happens. It simply reaches end. To fix this, you'll need to somehow call `-(void)playerStartPlaying` at the same time as the `setRate:time:atHostTime` is executed on the `AVPlayer`. I guess you could start an `NSTimer` or `dispatch_time` and let it execute he method in exactly `nextPlay`-amount of time, but that would kinda defeat the purpose of this thing. Maybe not. You could try different stuff out. You probably CAN do this with some success, but I suggest finding a way to register for when the player started from the start. Maybe you can observe the `rate` or something, I don't know.. If you want to try it with a delayed method, you can try this:

```
double delayInSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.avplayer.currentItem.duration); //or something
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [self playerStartPlaying];
});
```

Just keep in mind that this is some recursive shit, so even if you pause the video, this will still keep calling after that duration. In that case I suggest making a `BOOL paused;` and cancel the execution of the entire `playerStartPlaying` if it's set to `YES`. ..and of course set `paused = YES;` whenever you want to pause, next to wherever you say `[player pause];`

If this actually works, but you still get flashes, I know there are several ways to improve this. For instance, the `CMTimeAdd()` should probably be using some kind of synchronization-tool to make sure the times add up using the correct `timeScale` etc.

I have now spent way too much time writing this, and it might not even work. I have no idea. Good luck and good night.